# ViewDoesNotExist when view is there on Django 1.9.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

Hello I beginner in python and even more in django framework.

I started reading djangobook.com and have setup a server on pythonanywhere. I made my first view which was something like `hello_world` and it worked. On the next step I made another view that will show the current date and time, but I split both views in different files called `hello_world.py` and `current_datetime.py` and they are in package called my_views. But when I uploaded the files both of them are throwing `ViewDoesNotExist` exception and for 2 hours I cannot find any solution.

Here is my django project and you can see the files in it -> https://github.com/SuperSane95/supersane_djangoapp

I really don't know what is causing the problem and I need your help, people.

Comment: djangobook.com is about 7 years/8 releases behind, you should not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't pointed your url routes to the methods, just the library they are in:

Make your url patterns like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^hello/$', hello_world.hello),
                   url(r'^time/$', current_datetime.current_datetime),
                   )
```

That said this is really outdated and may not properly work on Django, I'd suggest using the [most recent Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) and starting again.

Comment: Thanks mate, this solved my problem. I have other question now, since I am coming from java and c# world, what is the difference in this case if I write hello_world.hello or hello_world.hello(), because on java and C# parenthesis are must when calling a method.

Comment: Thats too in-depth to go into here, but basically you are passing Django a *reference* to the method as part of the urlpatterns, and then django will call it by adding the parenthesis if needed.

Comment: Thanks I got the main idea, I will research more in the network :)